# running IntelliJ idea from terminal prints everything has changed

Tags: intellij-idea

I use manjaro linux and run applications from the terminal. Recently when I type idea (running I assume idea.sh, as this is what the top of the terminal says), and try to minimize and expand the idea window the terminal prints "Everything has changed". Is this something I should care about or is it just some random text?

[everything has changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYTR.png)

Comment: Most likely this is just a debug message that you can ignore.

Comment: oh ok thanks @yole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the bundled JDK, should be already fixed in a later version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-854

Comment: Thanks. However I tried updating it and it said it's the latest versions. Are there multiple different programs?

Comment: You could try IDEA 2018.3 EAP. I also posted a link to this question there, let's see if there's a solution for stable versions.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, i'm not a big fan of early access versions and it doesn't bother me that much, so I think I'll wait for it to update automatically.